# Faker.js random number between 2 values

Tags: javascript, faker

This one is driving me a little mad, I'm sure it's simple but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Im using [Faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) and the following to generate my random number:

```
faker.random.number();
```

Works great, now if I want to do it between 2 numbers, how would I go about this?

I tried the following:

```
faker.random.number(10, 50);
```

However, that just gives me numbers from `0` to `10`. No idea what the `50` is doing.

Can anyone give me some directions to this please.

Comment: Idk the "faker way" but you could do `faker.random.number(40) + 10;`

Comment: Why not with simple js: `Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 10);` ?

Comment: @DasBeasto That doesn't work as the minimum I can get would always be 10

Comment: @mimo because I'm using Faker

Comment: @K20GH If you want between 10 and 50 wouldn't the minimum you want to get be 10?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

## Update 2023 for v8

Now moved to https://github.com/faker-js/faker, they changed it again:

```js
faker.number.int(options: number | {
  max: number,
  min: number
} = {}): number
faker.number.int() // 2900970162509863
faker.number.int(100) // 52
faker.number.int({ min: 1000000 }) // 2900970162509863
faker.number.int({ max: 100 }) // 42
faker.number.int({ min: 10, max: 100 }) // 57
```

source: https://fakerjs.dev/api/number.html#int

## Update 2021

Latest versions changed location of the function from `faker.random.number` to `faker.datatype.number`, https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/1156

## Original answer

You need to give an object to the function:

```
faker.datatype.number({
    'min': 10,
    'max': 50
});
```

So if you just pass a number, it will set it as the max value. The min value is 0 by default.

This is the implementation of the number function :

```
this.number = function (options) {

    if (typeof options === "number") {
      options = {
        max: options
      };
    }

    options = options || {};

    if (typeof options.min === "undefined") {
      options.min = 0;
    }

    if (typeof options.max === "undefined") {
      options.max = 99999;
    }
    if (typeof options.precision === "undefined") {
      options.precision = 1;
    }

    // Make the range inclusive of the max value
    var max = options.max;
    if (max >= 0) {
      max += options.precision;
    }

    var randomNumber = options.precision * Math.floor(
      mersenne.rand(max / options.precision, options.min / options.precision));

    return randomNumber;

  }
```

Comment: The fact that you can pass in params in this way is neither mentioned [in the demo page](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/examples/browser/index.html#random), nor in the [API docs](http://marak.github.io/faker.js/faker.random.html#-static-number__anchor)

Comment: The newest version is now changed, instead of `faker.random`, one should use `faker.datatype`

Comment: DEPRECATED syntax above

Comment: @HosMercury thanks for pointing out, updated my answer!

Comment: Use `faker.number.int()` as `faker.datatype.number()` is being deprecated as well

Answer (score 42):

From [Fakerjs github](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/wiki/Random)

**Whole Number faker.** *random.number(min,max)* Random number between 0 and "range".

```
faker.random.number(100); //returns 92
faker.random.number({min:5, max:10}); //returns 9
```

**Decimal number faker.** *finance.amount(min,max,decimal places)* Random number between "min" and "max" including decimals to X digits.

```
faker.finance.amount(9000,10000,4); //returns 9948.8363
```

**Boolean faker.** *random.boolean()*

```
faker.random.boolean(); //returns true
```

**Array Element faker.** *random.arrayElement(array[])* Selects a random element from an array of possible values. This function is useful to create custom lists of possibilities.

```
faker.random.arrayElement(["one","two","three","four"]); //returns "two"
var phTyp = faker.random.arrayElement(["cell","work","home"]); //returns "work"
```

**Object Element faker.** *random.objectElement(object{})* Selects a random element from an object, selects the value not the keys. This function is useful to create custom lists of possibilities.

```
faker.random.objectElement({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}); //returns 3
```

Comment: `faker.random.number()` appears to have been replaced by `faker.random.numeric()` https://fakerjs.dev/api/random.html#numeric

Answer (score 11):

I encountered a warning while running the `faker.random.number` function in my application using `faker@5.5.3`.

> Deprecation Warning: faker.random.number is now located in
> faker.datatype.number

The methods have been moved. A better fix would be to replace it with `faker.datatype.number()`.

```
faker.datatype.number(100); // return 88
faker.datatype.number({ min: 5, max: 10 }); // return 7
```

Comment: Yes, they have changed the library and this now is the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try passing a hash like below

```
faker.random.number({ min: 10, max: 50})
```

Comment: Please add additional context as to ***why*** this is the correct answer.

Comment: hey @DavidL, it think its clear enough. #keepingitsimple

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use this library:
https://github.com/faker-js/faker

and in addition to that, it creates these methods that it needed and that the library does not currently support.

```
export function getCreditCardBrand(): string {
  const brands = [
    'Visa',
    'MasterCard',
    'American Express',
    'Discover',
    'JCB',
    'Diners Club',
  ];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * brands.length);
  return brands[randomIndex];
}

export function getBoolean(): boolean {
  const booleans = [true, false];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * booleans.length);
  return booleans[randomIndex];
}

export function getRandomElement<T>(items: T[]): T {
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
}

interface NumberRange {
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

export function getRandomNumber(range: NumberRange): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (range.max - range.min + 1)) + range.min;
}
```